# How to send Image as an attachment through Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

I am creating an application in which when we submit form that time I am creating QR Code using form data and saving that Image on network drive. Now I want to send that saved image on mail as attachment.

Below is my procedure from which I want to send image attachment as blob

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEND_MAIL_RECIPIENT_ATTACH (
                                       p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_cc        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_bcc       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_text_msg  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_html_msg  IN CLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_name1 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_mime1 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_blob1 IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                       --p_attach_name2 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       --p_attach_mime2 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       --p_attach_blob2 IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
  l_boundary    VARCHAR2(50) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
  l_step        PLS_INTEGER  := 57;

  PROCEDURE process_recipients(p_mail_conn IN OUT UTL_SMTP.connection,
                               p_list      IN     VARCHAR2)
  AS
    l_tab string_api.t_split_array;
  BEGIN
    IF TRIM(p_list) IS NOT NULL THEN
      l_tab := string_api.split_text(p_list);
      FOR i IN 1 .. l_tab.COUNT LOOP
    UTL_SMTP.rcpt(p_mail_conn, TRIM(l_tab(i)));
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END;


BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  process_recipients(l_mail_conn, p_to);
  process_recipients(l_mail_conn, p_cc);
  process_recipients(l_mail_conn, p_bcc);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  IF TRIM(p_cc) IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'CC: ' || REPLACE(p_cc, ',', ';') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;
  IF TRIM(p_bcc) IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'BCC: ' || REPLACE(p_bcc, ',', ';') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  IF p_text_msg IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_text_msg);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  IF p_html_msg IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_html_msg);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  -- First Attachement
  IF p_attach_name1 IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || p_attach_mime1 || '; name="' || p_attach_name1 || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_attach_name1 || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_attach_blob1) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_attach_blob1, l_step, i * l_step + 1))) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    END LOOP;

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;
  -- Second Attachement
  --IF p_attach_name2 IS NOT NULL THEN
    --UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    --UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || p_attach_mime2 || '; name="' || p_attach_name2 || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    --UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    --UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_attach_name2 || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    --FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_attach_blob2) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      --UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_attach_blob2, l_step, i * l_step + 1))) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    --END LOOP;

    --UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  --END IF;



  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);
   -- Pause for 1 second.
--  DBMS_LOCK.sleep(1);
--  dbms_lock.sleep(100);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END SEND_MAIL_RECIPIENT_ATTACH;
```

Below is my procedure I am calling from my c# code

```
create or replace PROCEDURE XX_VMS_SEND_QRCODE_MAIL ( 
  V_ATTACH_NAME1 IN VARCHAR2,
  V_ATTACH_MIME1 IN VARCHAR2,
  V_ATTACH_BLOB1 IN BLOB 
  
)AS
BEGIN

        SEND_MAIL_RECIPIENT_ATTACH
        (
          P_TO        => 'abc@gmail.com',
          P_CC        => '', 
          P_BCC       => '',
          P_FROM      => 'xyz@abc.com', 
          P_SUBJECT   => 'VMS test',
          P_HTML_MSG  => 'HI',
          P_ATTACH_NAME1 => V_ATTACH_NAME1,
          P_ATTACH_MIME1 =>  V_ATTACH_MIME1 ,
          P_ATTACH_BLOB1 =>  V_ATTACH_BLOB1  ,
          P_SMTP_HOST => 'smtp.xxx.com',
          P_SMTP_PORT => 25    
        ); 
    
    END XX_VMS_SEND_QRCODE_MAIL;
```

Below is my c# code from which I am retrieving my png image from network drive and converting into byte array.

```
public object sendQR()
        {
            object obj;
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnString);
            Image f = Image.FromFile(@"\\data\Public\abc\59.png");
            var obj1 = new ImageConvertor();
            byte[] imageByteArray = obj1.ConvertImageToByteArray(f, ".png");
            try
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

                oracleConnection.Open();
                cmd.Connection = oracleConnection;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "XX_VMS_SEND_QRCODE_MAIL";
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@V_ATTACH_NAME1", "QR_CODE.png");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@V_ATTACH_MIME1", "image/png");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@V_ATTACH_BLOB1", imageByteArray);
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                //DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Table"];
                obj = ds;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                oracleConnection.Close();
                oracleConnection.Dispose();
                return dataSet;
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

I am getting this exception:

> ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested while sending png on mail

Comment: I'm no ODP.Net expert but don't you have specify parameter *type* somewhere? ie  OracleDbType.Blob

Comment: When my image size is less then 32kb then obove code is working fine and when Image size is more then 32kb then i am getting above mentioned error